# I can't use my iPod touch (32GB)

Tags: 10.10, rhythmbox, ipod

I have connected my ipod touch 32gb in my ubuntu 10.10 os.It's connected on os and shows in desktop. but it's not showing as a device in Rhythmbox music player. and also I can't open directly like folder or drive or usb device. when I try to open it show this Error:

```
Could not display "gphoto2://[usb:001,003]/".

Error: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.207 was not provided by any .service files

Please select another viewer and try again.
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: What generation is your ipod touch?

Comment: How to find which generation of my Ipod? I can see ipod name and 32GB and touch on it.

Comment: Erm, I don't have one.. Maybe post the output of `dmesg|grep -i ipod`?

Comment: Also, you might just post the model number. My old ipod has some info at Settings > About.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your iPod is using a newer firmware than supported by ubuntu 10.10 out of the box.

The packages which are needed for using iPod, iPhone etc. are libimobiledevice1 libplist1 libgpod4 libusbmuxd1 usbmuxd gvfs and gvfs-backends. With the ppa ppa:pmcenery/ppa you are maybe able to solve this problem.

*First of all: You have be clear about the fakt, that a ppa (personal package archive) is neither part of ubuntu nor a save repository. (It's like downloading a pice of software for windows from any website)*

To install these packages from this ppa you should act like the following:

1. Open the software-center.
2. Go to "Software Sources…" under "Edit".
3. type in your user password.
4. Go to the Tab "Other Software" and "add" a new repository.
5. there you have to add "ppa:pmcenery/ppa"
6. update your System.

If after that your iPod still not works try the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice1 libplist1 libgpod4 libusbmuxd1 usbmuxd gvfs gvfs-backends
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple borked linux support with iOS 4 and Nano 6+, and it's proven difficult to hack the music database to allow access to non-iTunes apps. I suspect your device is included in the bug.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631006